# service vs. initctl in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, services, daemon, init

Why are some deamons run out of `service` and some out of `initctl` in Ubuntu? Do both tools do the same thing and it is just a matter of personal preference of the user what they will use?

E.g.

```
sudo service --status-all
```

vs

```
sudo initctl list
```

In my particular instance `cron` runs out of `initctl`, and `ssh` runs out of `service`. But on Fedora, for example, both of those will be in `systemctl`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some distributions are replacing the legacy **System V** to manage services. Ubuntu uses **upstart** while Fedora uses **systemd**. Generally speaking do the same, but systemd is more different that upstart respect System V. upstart is based in events, whereas systemd try to do aggressive parallelization and manage not only services, but sockets, devices, etc.

HTH